Shiny Server Render html file - save to www folder for using it on a iframe
What I'm trying is to generate a dynamic html (public report) to print with a thermal printer
I have an rmd with parameters in a shiny-server app.  I want to save the "file.hmtl" result in the public folder www for using it in a iframe.
I can generate and download the "file.html" from the temp directory, buy I can't copy it.
This is the actual code.  Works fine if I manually save a "ticket.html" file in the www folder - also works fine locally copy form temp folder to www folder - I think is permission problem with shiny-server folder on file.copy
    resp <- data.frame("Ticket" = 2983, 'product' =  "Black Angus cheeseburger")
    params <- list(datos = resp)

    curdir <- getwd()
    src <- normalizePath('ticket.Rmd')
    owd <- setwd(tempdir())
    on.exit(setwd(owd))
    file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
    out <- rmarkdown::render('report.Rmd', 
              output_format = 'html_document', params = params, 
              envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    
    resp <- file.copy(out, paste0(curdir,'/www/ticket.html'), overwrite = TRUE)
    
    showModal(div(class = "modal-ticket",
                  modalDialog(tags$iframe(src='ticket.html',
                                          scrolling = 'no',
                                          height = '350px'),
                              easyClose = TRUE, size = 'l',
                              footer = modalButton("No ticket")
                  ))
    )


What are you calling "shiny-server"? Do you mean you don't use a local app?

Yes, im working on a digitalocen shiny sirve.

I found the problem... file.copy require permissions in server.  I solved the problem making shiny owner of the folder www in my shiny srv
